# Dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.1 on separate hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-10, hybrid

This is my system:

Asus N552VW (my bios mode is **Legacy**):

128GB SSD: my windows 10 is installed on it

2 TB HDD (partitioned to two 1000 GB): 250 GB shrinked for Ubuntu

My question is: looking at the picture below, which device should I use for **boot loader** installation ? Ubuntu installation
[Ubuntu installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ03R.jpg)

update:

I think this can help:
[boot priorities in bios menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JvWF.jpg)

Comment: Assuming your Windows boot-loader is installed on `sda`, you should install Grub to `sdb`.

Comment: doing what you've said, Would I get two entries in grub menu (one for Windows 10 and one for Ubuntu)?

Comment: If Windows fast start up or hibernation is enabled, the Linux NTFS driver cannot see the NTFS partitions. So then grub only boots working (not hibernated) Windows. So grub will offer to boot Windows as long as you keep fast start up off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: I faced a problem posted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117120/grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target

Answer (score 0):

**The simple mode**

Use two partitions on the HDD disk

- 242 GB for the root /
- 8 GB for a swap partition

When you create the partitions, select the boot device the sda.

**Recommended method**

The 242 GB of the root partition. Divide it in two:

- 60 GB to mount the linux root: /
- 182 to mount the user directories: /home

Same as the previous suggestion. Select the boot device to disk sda.
(remember the swap partition 8GB)

Comment: New versions of Ubuntu now use a swap file by default, no swap partition required. But if you do create a swap partition, then it will be used.

Comment: @oldfred, You are right. I'm used to doing partitions, by servers.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: I faced a problem posted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117120/grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target

Answer (score 0):

Having similar case, I did:

1. I left original Windows bootloder on sda
2. I installed Grub on sdb
3. I set up BIOS to boot from sdb by default

Grub menu still allows me to boot in Linux or Windows. But if something goes wrong, I can revert in BIOS and still boot in Windows, or even use BIOS F12 menu to choose system.

Btw. can't you somewhat place swap on SSD? This sometimes is very helpful.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. your suggestion is exactly the opposite of the one above. I still in doubt whether to choose sda or sdb. But I must say that in my boot priorities (in bios menu) I only see the SSD hard drive (sda).

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: Let me say this way: default choice of "green" user is sda, so Grub replaces Windows 10 bootloader. I took another approach that gave me some additional features. But if you do not know what and why, maybe really use sda.