# grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, hybrid

This is my system:

Asus N552VW (my bios mode is Legacy):

128GB SSD: my windows 10 is installed on it

2 TB HDD (partitioned to two 1000 GB): 250 GB shrinked for Ubuntu

during partitioning I create a logical / partition and selected sda for installing the grub boot loader. However, I got this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeQA9.jpg)

This may help:
[my partitions in windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6ooN.png)

Comment: Run the installer in Legacy mode, as the error shows you must have booted using EFI

Comment: I've searched a lot. Could you say how can I run the installer in legacy mode?

Comment: Check the boot menu or turn off EFI in BIOS boot settings